# Android - WebView not loading images from webservice

Tags: android, webview, android-image

I am working on a live app, and at one place I am getting data with image. So, I parsed it using `XML Parsing` but, when I try to `loaddata` in `webview` then it does not display image, just displays the text.

```
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.test_webview1);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    webview.loadData(test.Description.get(index),"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Which setting of `webview` that I am missing??

Answer (score 1):

Are the links Absolute(e.g. "http://foo.com/image.png"), or relative(e.g. "image.png")?
If they are relative, then your WebView does not know what domain should it load images from.

**EDIT**
Please try using `loadDataWithBaseURL` instead of `loadData`. It should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
WebSettings settings = yourWebWiew.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```